# How to disable keyboard shortcut for manage pallet?

Tags: node-red

In node-red, via setting.js file, i disabled menu item  "menu-item-edit-palette" for my dashboard.
But Ctrl+Shift+P key board short cut which can be used to open Palette is functional.
How to disable it?

```
editorTheme: {               
    menu: {
     /** Hide unwanted menu items by id. see editor/js/main.js:loadEditor for complete list */
     "menu-item-keyboard-shortcuts": false,
     "menu-item-edit-palette": false
   }
}
```

Expected:
When I disable menu item, related key board short cut also should not work.

Actual:
Key boardshort cuts working even though menu items disabled via setting

Answer (score 3):

You can totally disable the manage pallet option 2 ways:

Adding the following to the settings.js

```
editableTheme: {
   palette: {
      editable: false
   }
}
```

or making sure that npm is not available to the node-red process.

Comment: This was very helpful.. Thank you,